# mysql range query , use index judge range large

Tags: mysql, indexing, range, range-query

mysql table struct 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

it make me confuse, if query range influence use index in mysql 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please add your SQL to the question, instead of using screenshots. Also, please include a succinct question showing what you need help with and a reduced version of code that shows what is breaking.

Answer (score 1):

That is what happens.  And it is actually an optimization.

When using a secondary key (such as `INDEX(teacher_id)`), the processing goes like this:

1. Reach into the index, which is a B+Tree.  In such a structure, it is quite efficient to find a particular value (such as `1`) and then scan forward (until `5000` or `10000`).
2. For each entry, reach over into the data to fetch the row (`SELECT *`).  This uses the `PRIMARY KEY`, a copy of which is in the secondary key.  The PK and the data are clustered together; each lookup by one PK value is efficient (again, a BTree), but you need to do 5000 or 10000 of them.  So the cost (time taken) adds up.

A "table scan" (ie, not using any `INDEX`) goes like this:

1. Start at the beginning of the table, walk through the B+Tree for the table (in PK order) until the end.
2. For each row, check the `WHERE` clause (a range on `teacher_id`).

If more than something like 20% of the table needs to be looked at, a table scan is actually faster than bouncing back and forth between the secondary index and the data.

So, "large" is somewhere around 20%.  The actual value depends on table statistics, etc.

Bottom line:  Just let the Optimizer do its thing; *most* of the time it knows best.

Answer (score 0):

in brief,  i use mysql database
execute

`EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM t_teacher_course_info 
WHERE teacher_id  >1 and teacher_id < 5000`

will use index `` INDEX `idx_teacher_id_last_update_time` (`teacher_id`, `last_update_time`) ``

but if change range 

`EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM t_teacher_course_info 
WHERE teacher_id  >1 and teacher_id < 10000`

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

1   1   SIMPLE  t_teacher_course_info   ALL idx_teacher_update_time             671082  Using where

scan all table, not use index , any mysql config
maybe scan row count judge if use index. !!!!!!!